# Receive on multiple channels

Tags: go, channel

In golang for receiving on multiple channels I should use following construction:

```
for {
    select {
    case chan1:
    case chan2:
    }
}
```

Whant if I don't know the exact number of channel I will receive on?

Is it possible somehow to listen from some object which contains arbitrary (runtime defined) number of `channel`s?